# Are awlia al shaytan what is termed psychopaths in the west?

Tags: shaitan

Psychopaths ( a medical term)are known to have no empathy and prey on those that are extra nice Like empaths they have the colloquial name "energy vampires" because they seek to harvest the good in people. 
When contrasted to awlia al shaytan I find many similarities:
"Muslim believes that Shaytan has evil companions that are overpowered by him and consequently forget about their Lord. He seduced them to evil, encouraging them to falsehood, deafening them from hearing the truth, blinding them from seeing the proofs, so that they are subordinate to him, obeying his commands. He misled them to mischief by making it attractive to them, until they consider evil to be good and good to be bad. Thus, they became enemies and opponents to the Awliya' of Allah"

Comment: Could you add a source for your quote and explain why you assume that awlia al shaytan are what we call psychopaths?

Comment: http://nuralislaamarticles.tripod.com/id146.html

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

First let me recommend you a short booklet, this will cover each and everything about the aulia of 2 kinds, and their differences.

> Name:
>   الفرقان بین اولیا الرحمن و اولیا الشیطن
>  Al-furqan, bain al aulia
>   al-rahman, wa aulia al-shaitaan
>
> Writer: Shiekh ul islam imam ibn-etaimia R.A
>  Language(Origonal): Arabic
>   *[Download urdu translation from here](https://islamhouse.com/ur/books/462241/) (And you can lookup for origonal arabic version or english translations)*

I will try to be short, the above quote you quoted(without a source) is not like the DEFINITION of aulia al-shaitaan. It do presents some of the cases of them though.

Now, let me quote some ayats from quran about them:

> So when you recite the Qur'an, [first] seek refuge in Allah from
>   Satan, the expelled [from His mercy]. Indeed, there is for him no
>   authority over those who have believed and rely upon their Lord. **His
>   authority is only over those who take him as an ally and those who
>   through him associate others with Allah** . quran 16/98-100
>
> **We have made the devils allies to those who do not believe. And when
>   they commit an immorality, they say, "We found our fathers doing it,
>   and Allah has ordered us to do it." Say, "Indeed, Allah does not order
>   immorality. Do you say about Allah that which you do not know?"** Say,
>   [O Muhammad], "My Lord has ordered justice and that you maintain
>   yourselves [in worship of Him] at every place [or time] of
>   prostration, and invoke Him, sincere to Him in religion." Just as He
>   originated you, you will return [to life] - A group [of you] He
>   guided, and a group deserved [to be in] error. **Indeed, they had taken
>   the devils as allies instead of Allah while they thought that they
>   were guided.** Quran 7/27-30
>
> **And indeed do the devils inspire their allies [among men] to dispute
>   with you.** And if you were to obey them, indeed, you would be
>   associators [of others with Him]. Quran 6/121

We can conclude some things from these ayah that these people are mostly disbelievers and they not necessarily know that what they are doing is wrong, they mostly do it because they think it is the right way, not only that, they don't want to understand the truth, and they don't accept the truth. Maybe because shaitaan is putting wasawas in their heads because it is controlling them or maybe they just not want to.

Now, this seems different from **usual psychopath definition.** which is:

> **A person suffering from chronic mental disorder with abnormal or
>   violent social behaviour.**(Google)

**This is clearly different from the concept of aulia al-shaitaan**(friends of shaitaan). Because, wali(friend) of shaitaan does not necessarily have to be socially violent. He does not need to feel good when he see others in pain, nor he necessarily need to harm others as fun. While **as we can see in above verses of quran that aulia of shaitaan they 

1) disbelieve(Do shirk etc) 

2) do adultery(zina) or fight against believers or do/encourage other bad things/sins thinking this is the right way.(Mostly, sometime they might know its wrong but they just don't want to accept for any reason.)**

So, we can conclude that these terms are not synonyms.

### Allah knows best

Comment: Salam alaykum I have already read awlia al shaytan and awlia al rahman by ibn thaimia.  O have understood awlia al shaytan as the antithesis of awlia al rahman and so the most bad of human kind and the psychopaths fall into this category I have been researching psychopaths for some time and brother no one on this dynya is near them in bad actions uthubillah.

Comment: Thats really great, but still, we can say at-least that all aulia al-shaitaan are not psychopaths. Because its not the same thing. Psychopaths, as i mentioned in my answer tend to feel good by hurting people, or by seeing people in pain. While aulia al-shaitaan does not need to do so as per the ayah i quoted above.

Comment: you seem to be in mind that a psychopath must be sadistic i.e. enjoy inflicting pain on others but in ibn thaymia book the awlia al shaytan come in degrees and not all psychopaths are sadistic what defines the essence of a psychopath is their lack of empathy they don`t feel for others they describe that from they were born to the day they die. Some have linked it to a genetic hereditary also worth mentioning is that they have choice and know good from bad its not kike they are mentally ill where the pen has been lifted from them.

Comment: Let me give you an example, the people who do magic etc with the help of shaitaan, they are also aulia al-shaitaan, i don't think i need to explain this. But, would you consider them psychopaths?

Comment: Well brother if a person does black magic in order to profit and he knows that it will harm someone I consider it a psychopathic trait since they are showing no empathy for others so someone who goes to a magician might not be a psychopath but a magician who does this his entire life is most probably a psychopath right?

Comment: That seems right, but also consider in the above ayah, allah says, that aulia of shaitaan disbelieve and they dont accept the true path saying that their elders were on the same path so this is the right path. Would you also classify these people as psychopaths?

Comment: It seems awlia al shaytan come on various degrees and so do psychopaths even the psychopath score used on psychiatry has a range.Yes I would from what I read from magician for examplenisbthatbthier trade is inherited from their fathers. Same for psychopathic monarchs e.g. Pharaohs who inherit kingdom and self proclaimed divinity from their fathers.

Comment: alright, lets take another case, the people who are very strict about religion, and if their religeon happens to be islam, and they are following it without thinking about it, even saying because their parents did so. And they don't care about anyone or anything means they are very strict about their beliefs. Than by same defination and reasoning one can say they are psychopaths, but they are nto aulia al-shaitaan

Comment: No you misunderstand following in the footsteps of your forefathers don't make you a psychopath I gave examples of people who are psychopaths and follow in their forefathers footsteps. They are not mutually exclusive!

Comment: But it seems like same thing, one is following forefathers when they were wrong, and other is following his forefathers when they were right... both don't listen to anyone about religion, they are strict about it, they stick to their religions and they both try to overcome the other religion....